# SonarQube 6.4 Incorrect "New Bugs" Count

Tags: sonarqube

Our nightly run of SonarQube 6.4 has been reporting "New Bugs" that -- when double-checked against git -- are months old.

Example: we have a java file that is being flagged as having a new bug (code smell) introduced 3 days ago. However, according to git...

1. The file itself has not been touched in 11 days
2. The developer "assigned" to this by Sonar hasn't touched the file in
   18 months
3. The specific line of code Sonar is complaining about was introduced
   in 2015
4. There have been no recent updates to Sonar installation
5. Our ruleset (a renamed, vanilla copy of "Sonar way") has not changed
   in at least 3 months

We would like devs to check every day for new Sonar violations, but if we can't rely upon them being correct that won't work. Hoping someone here knows why this might be happening...

Comment: Further strangeness... Sonar is reporting that the issue was "Closed(Fixed)" some days ago. However:
1. The questionable code is still in the file, and...
2. according to git, the file has still not been touched

Comment: have you changed the version of the language plugin included? Was there a change in the Quality Profile or a change in the Quality Profile associated to the project? When was the last successful analysis of the project? Something must have changed.

Comment: No to all. There have been zero changes to our SonarQube installation, configuration, or rules since the time I first posted. We are purposefully not making changes there until we can eliminate or at least identify the source of the strange behaviors we are seeing.